# how to get file seals for a file descriptor

Tags: linux

On Linux (and FreeBSD AFAIK) there is a concept of "file seals". From the fcntl(2) man page:

> File seals limit the set of allowed operations on a given file.  For each seal that is
> set on a file, a specific set of operations will fail with EPERM on this file from now on.
> The file is said to be  sealed.

For a Java app where write() and fallocate() syscalls fail with EPERM I'd like to confirm that these errors are called by file seal.

Is it possible to get the seals for given file descriptor using a command line tool ?